# Wordpress custom block error: Content generated by `save` function triples

Tags: plugin-development, errors

The block itself works fine. The problem is when the post is edited again - the block gives a "This block contains unexpected or invalid content" message. Developer console shows the following error:

```
blocks.min.js?ver=639e14271099dc3d85bf:10 Block validation: Block validation failed for `create-block/schedule-item` ({name: 'create-block/schedule-item', icon: {…}, keywords: Array(0), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="wp-block-create-block-schedule-item"><div><div>1</div><div><div>3</div><div>2</div></div></div><div><div><div>1</div><div><div>3</div><div>2</div></div></div><div><div>1</div><div><div>3</div><div>2</div></div></div></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="wp-block-create-block-schedule-item"><div>1</div><div><div>3</div><div>2</div></div></div>
```

So, basically, the save function apparently generates triple the content, despite it showing fine on frontend.

Here is the block save function:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save({
        className: 'wp-block-create-block-schedule-item',
    });
    const { time, speaker, event, align } = attributes;
    const className = blockProps.className;

    return (<div {...blockProps}>
                <RichText.Content
                    tagName="div"
                    value={time}
                />
                <div>
                    <RichText.Content
                        tagName="div"
                        value={speaker}
                    />
                    <RichText.Content
                        tagName="div"
                        value={event}
                    />
                </div>
    </div>);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Raw block markup:

```
<!-- wp:create-block/schedule-item -->
<div class="wp-block-create-block-schedule-item"><div>13-45</div><div><div>Speakers</div><div>Event</div></div></div>
<!-- /wp:create-block/schedule-item -->
```

Seems to be in order.

Edit function:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import {
    useBlockProps,
    RichText,
    AlignmentControl,
    BlockControls,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: 'wp-block-create-block-schedule-item',
    });
    const { time, event, speaker, align } = attributes;

    const onChangeTime = (newContent) => {
        setAttributes({ time: newContent });
    };
    const onChangeSpeaker = (newContent) => {
        setAttributes({ speaker: newContent });
    };
    const onChangeEvent = (newContent) => {
        setAttributes({ event: newContent });
    };


    const onChangeAlign = (newAlign) => {
        setAttributes({
            align: newAlign === undefined ? 'none' : newAlign,
        });
    };

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <BlockControls>
                <AlignmentControl value={align} onChange={onChangeAlign} />
            </BlockControls>
            <RichText

                tagName="div"
                value={time}
                onChange={onChangeTime}
                placeholder={__('Time', 'basic-block')}
            />
            <div>
                <RichText

                    tagName="div"
                    value={event}
                    onChange={onChangeEvent}
                    placeholder={__('Event', 'basic-block')}
                />
                <RichText

                    tagName="div"
                    value={speaker}
                    onChange={onChangeSpeaker}
                    placeholder={__('Speaker', 'basic-block')}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And block.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "create-block/schedule-item",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Schedule Item",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "schedule-item",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "attributes": {
        "time": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "div"
        },
        "speaker": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "div"
        },
        "event": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "div"
        },
        "align": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not how you use `useBlockProps`, you can't pass only some of the props you have to pass all of the props of things won't work. Also where is your edit component? Would it not make more sense to wrap the richtext content in a div instead of using `tagName`? Can you edit your question to include the _raw_ block markup that's been saved to the database as well as your edit component?

Comment: Tom is right, use all `useBlockProps` on outer HTML element. However, this may also be caused by improper attribute definitions. Please share your block.json or wherever you have attributes defined.

Comment: Added raw block markup, edit, and block.json.

Comment: Edited the save function to use entire useBlockProps, but it still keeps returning triplicate.

Comment: After reading documentation, I guess "selector": "div" could cause this? Not sure. I have another block that has different selectors for the attributes (h4 and span), and it returns in duplicate - number of total attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using

> ```
>    "selector": "div"
> ```

for all attributes - it naturally used attributes from every div, hence triplicate.